# Gradle ProcessResources uptodatewhen

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a gradle task as below for replacing tokens while processing resources.

```
processResources {
filesMatching('**/application.yml') {
    filter org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            rootDir: rootProject.rootDir.getAbsolutePath() ,
            commitId: rootProject.gitMetadata.commitId
    ]
}
}
```

There are two problems I'm facing here:

1. Whenever I'm modifying the application.yml file, I'm being forced to manually execute the processResources task before I start the server (I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 14.1 edition.. though I add the processResources task before the server deploy, it isnt helping).
2. Though I execute the processResources at times, the output file isnt processsed correctly (Probably IntelliJ is copying the file to the output directory instead of gradle) and gradle thinks that the output is up-to-date.

The easiest way to fix the problem is to add the below statement

```
 outputs.upToDateWhen{false}
```

But, I'm not liking this solution because it almost defeats the purpose of using Gradle (its like a clean build).

What I wanted to do is probably allow Gradle to always ONLY process/re-process the application.yml file or put an if cond inside uptoDateWhen to inspect the output and then return true or false.

Is there a way to do it? Any other solutions/better ways are welcome!

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

After some trial and error this below solution works. But, I'm afraid if this would break scenarios where there could be other resources updated but not actually re-processed by this task.. Please let me know if this is correct...

```
processResources {
    //Re-Process the files only when the output application.yml file doesnt exist or if it contains the unresolved variables
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        File configFileOutput = file("${sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir}/config/application.yml")
        println configFileInput.absolutePath
        try {
            return !configFileOutput.text.contains('@')
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            // This means that the file is not present and thus the task should Run
            return false;
        }
    }
    filesMatching('**/application.yml') {
        filter org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
                rootDir: rootProject.rootDir.getAbsolutePath() ,
                commitId: rootProject.gitMetadata.commitId
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can configure IntelliJ and Gradle output folders to point the same location. When it comes to 1. how do you start the server? Via gradle task?

Comment: Not sure how to sync both of them.. Will research on that.. I start the server as a spring boot app on intellij...